# dnsproxy.py socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use

Tags: python, dns

I would like to modify the hosts file in my pc so to redirect all subdomains of mydomain.com using wildchar *,
to do this I would use this script phyton [dnsproxy.py](https://github.com/hubdotcom/marlon-tools/blob/master/tools/dnsproxy/dnsproxy.py)

I modified the /etc/hosts file by adding lines

85.217.170.9 mydomain.com

85.217.170.9 * .mydomain.com

I try to run the script but I get an error message

$ sudo python dnsproxy.py -s 8.8.8.8

socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use

which address in the message ??? how can I solve and run the script ???

(linux ubuntu16.04x64)

Comment: The address that you're trying to bind the socket to. Someone else is listening on the same address/port. Maybe it's another instance of your script? Check the network status using *netstat*.

Comment: that mean a socket are alerady Open on this port , you need to change the Port or Close first the Socket Who Are Connected